# I don't know why my images won't show up?

Tags: html, css

I am making myself a digital cv, and I can't get my images to show up on one of the pages.

The CSS and the HTML you can copy and use. Everything is working expect the images showing up, and I cannot understand why this is happening.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Crown Title;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.main {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 8px-16px;
}

img {
  background-color: none;
}

.content {
  background-color: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hamburger" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
  <a href="myStory.html">My Story</a>
  <a href="career.html">Career</a>
  <a href="education.html">Education</a>
  <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="contact1.html">Contact Us</a>
  <img alt="logo" src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/krisdog/krisdog1709/krisdog170900122/85720771-stock-vector-lion-standing-rampant-heraldic-crest-coat-of-arms.jpg?ver=6">
</div>
<!--Burger Icon-->
<span style="font-size 30px; cursor: pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

<div class="main">
  <!--Main Photo-->
  <h1>See The World Through My Eyes</h1>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQYOECNfDLyTYX5rEW8lFdhjTknabIrOH5amCPJYYIfWOFvNVLK&usqp=CAU" alt="happy" style="width:100%">
    <h3>Wedding</h3>
  </div>
  <!--Table Grid smaller Photos-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTMejgEW9M5tYts8sPMXHj67KOW5_uzT2qR9A0gwpi660qqYVRD&usqp=CAU" alt="colors" style="width: 100%; height:50%">
        <h3>Architecture</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR0rBotboUlDoTFx1iX0FsXpt4Z4VbvA_5E34b-jG1BSQqtJ6yO&usqp=CAU" alt="animals" style="width:100%">
        <h3>Animals</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSVA6mUCorGmSCDsSY4qwZvG_CTbmh_N0db-4a_Z1HDcd25ulZR&usqp=CAU" alt="my_love" style="width:100%, height:50%">
        <h3>Portrait</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRowQXo7erqtYGz-3pOsPVLcD-baQ4Cyz1RUH5e30tUtS0crWFY&usqp=CAU" alt="my_loves_handmande_food" style="width:100%"></img>
        <h3>Bento Box(M)</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/16/58/bc/1658bcc4bc5a3976845372f7f8eddd00.jpg" alt="actually_Katsu_Dragneel" style="width:100%"></img>
    <h3>Next Generation</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding the question but the image seem to be appearing perfectly fine in my end

Comment: images loaded properly for me https://jsfiddle.net/9syxh7L6/

Comment: Same here nothing seems missing